# Actionbar menu item: onOptionsItemSelected not being called

Tags: android

I am trying to use a menu item to execute some code, the menu item is shown in the actionbar but when I click the item it appears that the onOptionsItemSelected method is not called.

I have the two following methods I think may be the cause:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        Log.d("here", "clicked");
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.share:
                Log.d("here", "share");            
                return true;
            default:
                Log.d("here", "default");
                return false;
        }
    }
```

I have tried to output to the log at various places to see what might be happening but nothing is displayed in the log for either case, or before the switch statement. I can only assume the method is not being called but cannot figure out why.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I also have a up navigation button on the actionbar which displays the log messages from this method when clicked.

Comment: Is your menu.xml have your activity context? Like this: 
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context="org.your.app.MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/share"
          android:title="@string/share"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>

Comment: Try using Toast instead of Log, or try to debug it.

Comment: @Raskilas It did not have the activity context. I have added it but it still does not work.

Comment: @vilpe89 I will try that now.

Comment: @vilpe89 I replaced the Log with Toast but they toast was not displayed when I clicked the share button. It was however displayed when i click the up navigation button.

Comment: Post the R.menu.menu file's content.

Comment: Ah I have it working now. It was the context in the menu.xml file like Raskilas said. I had given it the wrong path. Thanks for your help